# Laravel 4 Excel import fails

Tags: php, laravel-4, import-from-excel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to import excel files but it always give me this error:

```
PHPExcel_Exception
Row 2 is out of range (2 - 1)
```

I'm using Laravel 4 and here's my code:

```
public function postExcel()
{
    $file = Input::file('file');

    $destinationPath = public_path() .'/uploads/temp/';
    $filename   = str_replace(' ', '_', $file->getClientOriginalName());
    $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

    $result = Excel::selectSheets('Sheet1')->load($destinationPath)->get();

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($result->toArray());
    exit;

}
```

This is my dummy excel file:
[image: dummy excel]

I've tried to google this but for other it seems like it only occurs when the sheet is more than one, but it's not like that in my case.

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: Also, you appear to be `load()`ing the `public/uploads/temp` folder, not the individual file.

Comment: the `$result = Excel::selectSheets('Sheet1')->load($destinationPath)->get();` line...
when I change it to: `$result = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($destinationPath, function($reader) {
   $reader->noHeading();
  })->get();` it gives no error but it returns null array... is it the excel file problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, but it seems weird to `selectSheets()` before you `load()` the file, and I'd guess you should be doing `load($destinationPath . $filename)` for starters.

Comment: Oh my bad! sorry, i forgot to add the filename, now it works! thanks a bunch!

Comment: Neat, added that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `load($destinationPath . $filename)`, not `load($destinationPath)` - the directory isn't an Excel file. :-)